# mongoose. updating embedded document in array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In the [a official mongoose site](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html) I've found how can I remove embedded document by _id in array:

```
post.comments.id(my_id).remove();
post.save(function (err) {
   // embedded comment with id `my_id` removed!
});
```

I'm interested how can I update instead removing this one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do

```
var comment = post.comments.id(my_id);
comment.author = 'Bruce Wayne';

post.save(function (err) {
    // emmbeded comment with author updated     
});
```

Comment: Save doesn't seem to fire when I update embedded documents - and marking it changed doesn't invalidate it either.

Answer (score 17):

It shoud look something like this:

```
    YOURSCHEMA.update(
        { _id: "DocumentObjectid" , "ArrayName.id":"ArrayElementId" },
        { $set:{ "ArrayName.$.TheParameter":"newValue" } },
        { upsert: true }, 
        function(err){

        }
    );
```

In this exemple I'm searching an element with an id parameter, but it could be the actual _id parameter of type objectId.

Also see: [MongooseJS Doc - Updating Set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) and [Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest docs on dealing with sub documents in Mongoose. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

```
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent');
var parent = new Parent;

// create a comment
parent.children.push({ name: 'Liesl' });
var subdoc = parent.children[0];
console.log(subdoc) // { _id: '501d86090d371bab2c0341c5', name: 'Liesl' }
subdoc.isNew; // true

parent.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err)
  console.log('Success!');
});
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to update the embedded document.