# How to update a object in mongodb via mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema as:

```
var Organization = new Schema({
  name: String,
  address: {
    street : String,
    city: String
  }
}, { collection: 'organization' });
```

How do I update only street part of address for an organization via mongoose?

Comment: i had found only about the subdocument array not about the simple object subdocument. In my case, i do not have subdocument array.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I can't find any docs that cover this simple case so I can see why you're having trouble.  But it's as simple as using a `$set` with a key that uses dot notation to reference the embedded field:

```js
OrganizationModel.update(
  {name: 'Koka'}, 
  {$set: {'address.street': 'new street name'}}, 
  callback);
```

Comment: I believe the preferred mechanism for updating via mongoose, is to use the mongoose wrapper, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose

Answer (score 6):

Now you can update directly .

```
OrganizationModel.update(
 {name: 'Koka'}, 
 {'address.street': 'new street name'}, 
 callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Document set](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set) also, specified properties can be updated. With this approach, we can use "save" which validates the data also.

```
  doc.set({
        path  : value
      , path2 : {
           path  : value
        }
    }
```

Example: Update Product schema using Document set and save.

```
// Update the product
let productToUpdate = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

if (!productToUpdate) {
  throw new NotFoundError();
}

productToUpdate.set({title:"New Title"});
await productToUpdate.save();
```

Note - This can be used to update the multiple and nested properties also.