# What are all of the possible callback params for mongoose Document#update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This seems really poorly documented.. The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) example just has `callback` being passed to update.  There is a link redirecting to `Model.update` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) and the example shows the parameters of the callback are `(err, numberAffected, raw)`.

Does the Document#update callback pass the same parameters?  I was hoping to get the updated document returned.  My initial search was based on [how to update a document in mongo db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose) but even the answer there doesn't explain or even list the params of the callback.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Poor documentation of callback parameters is something that's plagued many node.js libraries for some reason.  But MongoDB's `update` command (regardless of the driver) doesn't provide access to the updated doc, so you can be sure it's not provided to the callback.

If you want the updated document, then you can use one of the `findAndModify` methods like [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1}, {$inc: {count: 1}}, {new: true}, function (err, doc) {
    // doc contains the modified document
});
```

Starting with Mongoose 4.0 you need to provide the `{new: true}` option in the call to get the updated document, as the default is now `false` which returns the original.

Answer (score 0):

num-affected is actually raw mongoDB output and an **Object**. It looks like this:

```
{ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1}
```

unfortunately I have no idea what nModified property means.
'n' is the old (pre 4.0) number of affected rows

Comment: same is with me 
I have applied the callback as function (error , res) {
  inner code
}
but giving same as above