# mongoose upsert not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update field or insert document in MongoDB if document with field {"address": "8.8.8.8"} doesn't exists, see below.  I can't find document with that field

```
var Hosts = mongoose.model('Hosts',new Schema({address: String, model: String}),'repvpn');

console.log(output);
Hosts.update({"address": "8.8.8.8"},{"$set": output},{upsert: true}, function(err){
    if (err) console.log("ERROR");
});
Hosts.find({"address": "8.8.8.8"}, function (err, targets) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(targets)
});
```

It gives me the output below with []:

```
AC76BB string
{ AC76BB: '2015-05-02T12:13:35.057Z' }
[]
```

Comment: Haven't include mongoose.connect and mongoose.Schema but these are fine, I can read from db

Comment: Can you add the output of `console.log(output);`

Comment: The `Hosts.update` call is async, so try putting your `Hosts.find` call inside the update callback so that it doesn't occur until after the doc is upserted.

Comment: right , but still the document is not in db,  I am looking into it directly nms:PRIMARY> db.repvpn.find({"address":"8.8.8.8"})
nms:PRIMARY>

Comment: even Hosts.update({"address": "8.8.8.8"},{$set: output},{upsert: true}).exec(); doesn't insert document...where ooutput is { AC76BB: '2015-05-02T17:17:34.103Z' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because none of the fields of your `$set` value are in the `Hosts` schema, the `update` call becomes a noop.

For this to work, you'd either need to add the `AC76BB` field to your schema or set the [`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) option of the schema to `false`:

```
var Hosts = mongoose.model('Hosts', new Schema({
    address: String,
    model: String
}, {strict: false}), 'repvpn');
```