# Find one or create with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have

```
Page.findById(pageId).then(page => {
  const pageId = page.id;
   ..
});
```

My problem is that if no page id is given, it should just take the first available page given some conditions, which is done by

```
Page.findOne({}).then(page => {
  const pageId = page.id;
  ..
});
```

but if no page is found, it should create a new page and use this, which is done with

```
Page.create({}).then(page => {
  const pageId = page.id;
  ..
});
```

But how do I combine all this to as few lines as possible?

I have a lot of logic going on inside

```
page => { ... }
```

so I would very much like to do this smart, so I can avoid doing it like this

```
if (pageId) {
  Page.findById(pageId).then(page => {
    const pageId = page.id;
     ..
  });
} else {
  Page.findOne({}).then(page => {
    if (page) {
      const pageId = page.id;
      ..
    } else {
      Page.create({}).then(page => {
        const pageId = page.id;
        ..
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I am thinking I maybe could assign a static to the schema with something like

```
pageSchema.statics.findOneOrCreate = function (condition, doc, callback) {
  const self = this;
  self.findOne(condition).then(callback).catch((err, result) => {
    self.create(doc).then(callback);
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert an empty document here: `Page.create({}).then(page)` ?

Comment: Yes, that is intended :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Related to **Yosvel Quintero's** answer which didn't work for me:

```
pageSchema.statics.findOneOrCreate = function findOneOrCreate(condition, callback) {
    const self = this
    self.findOne(condition, (err, result) => {
        return result ? callback(err, result) : self.create(condition, (err, result) => { return callback(err, result) })
    })
}
```

And then use it like:

```
Page.findOneOrCreate({ key: 'value' }, (err, page) => {
    // ... code
    console.log(page)
})
```

Comment: I guess, for NodsJS and Mongoose users the good news is the 'mongoose-find-one-or-create' npm plug-in, works like charm and easy to patch like a plug-in to your DB schema. Hope it helps guys.

Comment: The answer is not atomic.

Comment: You are right. **Requirements**: NodeJs and Mongoose

Answer (score 58):

As per the Mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate):

As per [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24711713/1315105)

Model.findByIdAndUpdate()

"Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback."

In the options set upsert to true:

upsert: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false.

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { name: 'SOME_VALUE' }}, { upsert: true  }, callback)
```

Comment: If you don't have the id, findOneAndUpdate() also has the same upsert option: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Here's a good [comparison table of Mongoose update operations](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update), highlighting atomic ones.

Answer (score 13):

Promise `async/await` version.

```
Page.static('findOneOrCreate', async function findOneOrCreate(condition, doc) {
  const one = await this.findOne(condition);

  return one || this.create(doc);
});
```

Usage

```
Page.findOneOrCreate({ id: page.id }, page).then(...).catch(...)
```

Or

```
async () => {
  const yourPage = await Page.findOneOrCreate({  id: page.id }, page);
}
```

Comment: This is not atomic.

Comment: If more than one client write to the collection at the same time, it's possible that right after the `.findOne()` returns false, another client creates a document, then this code creates another one. See [atomicity](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#atomic-updates).

Comment: When does that become truth? I believe that if you have a good system design, your developers won't need to deal with that. If `findOne` is actually not good in many cases, I believe mongoose/mongodb would mark it deprecated. For simple, just think about above codes as a shortcut to `find or create`. Or using `upsert` as another answer mentioned.

Comment: No "good system design" can prevent the situation I've described. Sure, it's unlikely to happen in small developments, with rare writes. A good question to ask is, what really are the benefits of using the two-step method in this answer, vs. the single, atomic, step in [the findOneAndUpdate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102372/find-one-or-create-with-mongoose/50648255#50648255).

Answer (score 10):

Each Schema can define instance and [static methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-static) for its model. Statics are pretty much the same as methods but allow for defining functions that exist directly on your Model

Static method `findOneOrCreate`:

```
pageSchema.statics.findOneOrCreate = function findOneOrCreate(condition, doc, callback) {
  const self = this;
  self.findOne(condition, (err, result) => {
    return result 
      ? callback(err, result)
      : self.create(doc, (err, result) => {
        return callback(err, result);
      });
  });
};
```

Now when you have an instance of `Page` you can call `findOneOrCreate`:

```
Page.findOneOrCreate({id: 'somePageId'}, (err, page) => {
  console.log(page);
});
```

Comment: What would it look like with promises instead of callbacks?

Comment: It's `PagSchema.static` not `PageSchema.statics`

Comment: This is not atomic.

Answer (score 3):

One lines solution with `async/await`:

`const page = Page.findOne({}).then(p => p || p.create({})`

Comment: Not atomic. Atomic solutions must use .updateOne or .findOneAndUpdate, which have an `upsert` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a static method to the model, you can try to move some things around and at least not to have all these callback nested levels:

```
function getPageById (callback) {
  Page.findById(pageId).then(page => {
    return callback(null, page);
  });
}

function getFirstPage(callback) {
  Page.findOne({}).then(page => {
    if (page) {
      return callback(null, page);
    }

    return callback();
  });
}

let retrievePage = getFirstPage;
if (pageId) {
  retrievePage = getPageById;
}

retrievePage(function (err, page) {
  if (err) {
    // @todo: handle the error
  }

  if (page && page.id) {
    pageId = page.id;
  } else {
    Page.create({}).then(page => {
      pageId = page.id;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted here ignore that this pattern is most common when there's a unique index on a field or a combination of fields. This solution considers unique index violation errors correctly:

```
mongoose.plugin((schema) => {
  schema.statics.findOrCreate = async function findOrCreate(key, attrs) {
    try {
      return await this.create({ ...attrs, ...key });
    } catch (error) {
      const isDuplicateOnThisKey =
        error.code === 11000 &&
        Object.keys(error.keyPattern).sort().join(',') ===
          Object.keys(key).sort().join(',');
      if (isDuplicateOnThisKey) {
        const doc = await this.findOne(error.keyValue);
        doc.set(attrs);
        return await doc.save();
      }
      throw error;
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
await Post.findOrCreate({ slug: 'foobar' }, { title: 'Foo Bar', body });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
 var myfunc = function (pageId) {
  // check for pageId passed or not
 var newId = (typeof pageId == 'undefined') ? {} : {_id:pageId};

 Page.findOne(pageId).then(page => {
 if (page)
 const pageId = page.id;
 else {  // if record not found, create new

    Page.create({}).then(page => {
        const pageId = page.id;
    });
  }
});

 }
```