# Use FindOne with Mongoose to find ObjectId in JSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use `findOne()` on Mongoose to find ObjectId in Twitter JSON credentials from Twitter account.

I am using following schema and code:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    provider: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    twitter: JSON
});

User.findOne({
    'twitter.id_str': 123
}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
        user = new User({
            name: 'Full Name',
            email: 'mail@gmail.com',
            username: 'pseudo',
            provider: 'twitter',
            twitter: { id_str: 123 }
        });
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(user);
        });
    } else {
        console.log(user);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the Twitter `id_str` a Mongo/Mongoose Object ID or is that a Twitter user id? Either way if you're going to be searching on a field you will save yourself some headache to model it more specifically in your Schema.  Instead of `JSON` use the data type of each field in the object.

Comment: It's the Twitter ID profile. I stock this in twitter key.

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema to either:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    provider: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    twitterId: { type: Number, unique: true }
});
```

or

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    provider: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    twitter: { id: { type: Number, unique: true } }
});
```

The second is more like your current setup. If you use that schema, your search code could be a findOne with the optional `upsert` flag on `findOneAndUpdate()`:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
    'twitter.id_str': 123
}, {
    name: 'Full Name',
    email: 'mail@gmail.com',
    username: 'pseudo',
    provider: 'twitter',
    twitter: { id_str: 123 }
}, {
    upsert: true
}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    } else {
        console.log(user);
    }
});
```

See here for another example of usage: [How do I update/upsert a document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)