# Save Or Update Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a nice way of either saving, or updating a document in mongoose? Something like what I'm after below

```
 let campaign = new Campaign({
        title: req.body.title,
        market: req.body.market,
        logo: req.body.logo,
        additional_question_information: question,
        status: status
    });

 campaign.saveOrUpdate().then(function() { ... }
```

Thanks for the help all

Comment: What is your question? What you are doing is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear at all.

I want to save a document if it doesn't exist, OR update a preexisting one with the new data. 

Is there a method to do that in mongoose? Seems like it'd be nice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update/upsert a document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose?)

Comment: See [Insert-or-Update with MongoDB and Mongoose](https://silvantroxler.ch/2016/insert-or-update-with-mongodb-and-mongoose/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update/upsert a document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is called an 'upsert'.

You can do this by using findOneAndUpdate and passing the { upsert: true } option, something like the below example:

```
let campaign = new Campaign({
        title: req.body.title,
        market: req.body.market,
        logo: req.body.logo,
        additional_question_information: question,
        status: status
    });

Campaign.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('CAMPAIGN ID TO SEARCH FOR')
}, campaign, { upsert: true }, function(err, res) {
    // Deal with the response data/error
});
```

The first parameter to findOneAndUpdate is the query used to see if you're saving a new document or updating an existing one. If you want to return the modified document in the response data then you can also add the `{ new: true }` option.

Documentation here for findOneAndUpdate: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: I think the braces { } around the campaign object in the .findOneAndUpdate call should not actually be there.

Comment: Good catch! Edited the answer.

Comment: Just an FYI doing a `findOneAndUpdate` does NOT set off any middlewares revolving around `save`. Reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MongoDB's findAndModify function. In mongoose this is natively supported by calling findOneAndUpdate(). Here is the documentation for it. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate
Notice that in the third argument it awaits for an object to be passed with options. You want to use `{ upsert : true }` in there to create a new document if one does not exist.