# How to push a json object in array in mongodb with loopback?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs

Here is my efforts :

```
async.waterfall([
            function(nextCall){
                MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    const dbo = db.db("testmdb");

               const criteria = {"_id":ObjectId(id)};
                    console.log("paymentInof[] ::: ",paymentInfo)
                    let obj = paymentInfo[0];
                    const query = {
                        $push:{payment:obj}                    
                    };

                    dbo.collection("Invoice").update(criteria, query);
                    db.close();
                    nextCall(null,{code:200});                                                                                                                                                                            
                });
            }
        ],function(err,results){
            if(err) return err;
            if(results.code === 200)
          console.log(chalk.blue(' ::: all done ::: '));
            next();
    });
```

Input from api explorer :

```
   {
  "payment":[{"transaction_at":"2018-02-12T06:04:35.279Z","paid_amount":350,"patient_id":"1233sssdd33","patient_urn":"214125","invoice_amount":700,"user":"me"}],
  "updated_by": "me"
}
```

Everything working fine but unable to push instead overwriting the existing object in payment array.

While from mongo shell it is working fine.

Please help me , where I am doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: no changed , similar overwriting the array object

Comment: You needs to use  {upsert: true} for adding new records, please check answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check mongoose `update` `upsert` option.

**Update options**

There are several option values that can be used with an update

`multi` - update all records that match the query object, default is false (only the first one found is updated)

`upsert` - if true and no records match the query, insert update as a new record

`raw` - driver returns updated document as bson binary Buffer, default:false

Please check the documentation to [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html).

Use following code,

```
 async.waterfall([
          function(nextCall){
              MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                  if (err) throw err;

                  const dbo = db.db("testmdb");

                  let criteria = {"_id": ObjectId(id)};
                  let obj = paymentInfo[0];
                  let query = { $push: { payment: obj } }

                  dbo.collection("Invoice").update(criteria, query, {upsert:true});
                  db.close();
                  nextCall(null,{code:200});                                                                                                                                                                            
              });
          }
      ],function(err,results){
          if(err) return err;
          if(results.code === 200)
        console.log(chalk.blue(' ::: all done ::: '));
          next();
  });
```

Also please check the similar type of question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose).

Hope this will help you!!