# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate tries to override _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my createUpdate function

```
const createUpdateProfile = (req, res) => {
    //Fillout Schema
    let uuid = req.user.identities[0].id;
    let provider = req.user.identities[0].provider;
    let email = req.user.email;
    let firstName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    let lastName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
    let pictureUrl = req.user.picture;
    let profileToSafe = new Profile({
        uuid: uuid,
        provider: provider,
        email: email,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        pictureUrl: pictureUrl
    });
    let profileToUpdate = new Profile({
        email: email,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        pictureUrl: pictureUrl
    });
    //createUpdate
    Profile.findOne({ uuid }).then(object => {
        if (object !== null) {
            Profile.findByIdAndUpdate(object._id, profileToUpdate, function (err, raw) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('callback -> err', err);
                }
                console.log('callback -> raw', raw);
                res.status(200).send('successful operation update');
            });
        } else {
            profileToSafe.save();
            res.status(200).send('successful operation create');
        }
    })
}
```

Everything works, despite updating an existing record.

So the problem is in this code area:

```
Profile.findByIdAndUpdate(object._id, profileToUpdate, function (err, raw) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('callback -> err', err);
                    }
                    console.log('callback -> raw', raw);
                    res.status(200).send('successful operation update');
                });
```

I have no idea why, but it is trying to override the _id field, even if it is not defined in the profileToUpdate schema.

Answer (score 1):

Got it work, after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855281/8370399).

The trick is to remove the id manually, before trying to update.

```
Profile.findOne({ uuid }).then(object => {
    if (object !== null) {
        var upsertData = profileToUpdate.toObject();
        delete upsertData._id;
        Profile.update({ uuid }, upsertData, { upsert: true }, function (err, raw) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('callback -> err', err);
            }
            console.log('callback -> raw', raw);
            res.status(200).send('successful operation update');
        });
    } else {
        profileToSafe.save();
        res.status(200).send('successful operation create');
    }
})
```