# Does Mongoose have a way to query for documents and create new ones if they don't exist, all in one query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to update a collection in my MongoDB. Basically, I want to take a list of email addresses, check if they exist in the DB, and if they don't, create a new User from them, all in the same query. Is this possible?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
const usersWithEmailsOnly = [<array-of-emails];

User.update({
   email: {
      $in: usersWithEmailsOnly.map(userWithEmail => userWithEmail.email),
   },
}, { multi: true, upsert: true }).exec()
```

And I get this response back from the server:

`{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

And when I look at the DB, I see that no users are created. Is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update/upsert a document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)

Comment: I've looked at that one but it doesn't seem to discuss handling multiple documents at once. Is this possible?

Comment: mongo has db.coll.updateMany (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany) but I'm unsure what that matches up with in mongoose

Comment: Based on your response back from server, it’s looks like no documents inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

```
Users.bulkWrite(
  usersWithEmailsOnly.map(userWithEmail =>
    ({ 
      "updateOne": {
        "filter": { "email": userWithEmail.email },
        "update": { "$setOnInsert": { "name": userWithEmail.name } },
        "upsert": true
      }
    })
  )
)
```

This couples with the [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) update operator which has the special condition that it's specified arguments *only* update the document when an actual *"upsert/insert"* happens. So an existing document that is matched simply receives no changes when this is the only operator used.

Note that *"upserts"* will always apply the criteria used in the *query/predicate* part of the update statement, as long as the expression equates to a singular value; i.e `age: { $gt: 3 }` would not be *singular*. For most *"data loading"* you would typically want creation of a static predicate as the *"unique key"* and therefore selector for the update as well as *some* other data, which would be where you apply a [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) as needed.

Technically it is still *multiple updates* but unlike attempting to loop a series of updates in code this is a *single request and response to and from the server*. It pretty much has the same responsiveness of a *single write* ( of course with the payload overhead ) from the point of view of your application.

There is no such thing as a true *"single statement"* as differing criteria for the data to update cannot be applied to multiple documents in a MongoDB update. You can apply the *same* data to update over multiple documents, but when you want *"this condition to match a document also means I update with this specific data when that happens"*, then that is what you use [`bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) for.

Comment: This is super informative. Thankyou so much this worked exactly for what I needed :D You are a saint and you deserve much praise

Comment: Is there any way to change this so that if the email DOES exist, it runs an `{ $addToSet: { events: eventId }}` operation and only updates that one specific field?

Comment: @StevieStar Yes. `$addToSet` would be applied both on match or on upsert. All other [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/) with the **exception** of `$setOnInsert` basically apply to every match *including* upserts.

Comment: Nice :D So would the update syntax end up looking like ```update: {
              $addToSet: { myEvents: req.body.eventId },
              $setOnInsert: { email: user.email },
            },```?

Comment: @StevieStar The `$setOnInsert` is not required for `email` because that's already in the **predicate**. That's what I explained in the question. You only use it for fields not in the predicate that you want **only** on insertion. i.e We are attempting to match on `email`, so if nothing is found that value is automatically inserted.