# How can I update a document in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to allow users to update existing mongoose documents using a form with method-override package.  I have read the other Stackoverflow posts on the issue, but none of them seem to resolve my problem. I want the user to be able to see their existing document they created, submit the form with new values, and have it update the database.

I have tried the solution provided here [How do I update/upsert a document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose) among others and it hasn't worked.

I have setup this initial route to show the individual document:

```
// EDIT - edit location route
router.get("/location/:id/edit", function(req, res) {
    Location.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundLocation){
        res.render("./locations/edit", {location: foundLocation});
    });
});
```

Which leads them to a landing page with this form to update the information on that document

```
<form action="/location/<%= location._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="location[name]" ></div>
     <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="location[image]" value="<%= location.image %>"></div>
      <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="location[longDescription]" value="<%= location.longDescription %>"></div>
       <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button></div>
</form>
```

The route that handles that PUT logic is:

```
router.put("/location/:id", function(req, res) {
    Location.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.location, {new: true}, function(err, updatedLocation){
        console.log(req.body.location);
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/search");
        } else {
            console.log(updatedLocation);
            res.redirect("/location/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

The issue I'm having is this route isn't firing any errors, but it also isn't updating the document. I've tried to console.log the req.body.location and it is returning undefined. I feel that may be the issue but I'm not sure how to fix it

@Deda this is what is logged in console.log(req.body)

````
  'location[image]':
   'https://wekivaisland.com/wp-content/uploads/bartlettimage-4977.jpg',
  'location[longDescription]': 'Edited Long Description' }
{ address:
   { street: '51 SW 11th Street Apt. 1537',
     city: 'Miami',
     state: 'FL',
     zip: '12345',
     country: 'United States' },
  author: { id: 5d081e0afd38374b43ca0c14, username: 'danny' },
  rating: 0,
  _id: 5d08dd702456a30948947c73,
  name: 'Random Place',
  image:
   'https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-yKPXCFHoNhQ/WPOOwjqA3QI/AAAAAAAABmQ/88DcGs-Cp5oXAv6fA6hn3J7NRUlYBaxgwCLcB/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-04-16%2Bat%2B11.33.00%2BAM.png',
  longDescription: 'Place #2',
  shortDescription: 'Place #2',
  __v: 0 }```


This has been resolved. I just needed to set bodyParser extended to true.

It has previously read

```app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));``

by changing this to the code below everything worked properly.

```app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));```
````

Comment: Looks like you have problem with the parsing request body, not with mongoose.
What is logged on `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: @Deda I added the response from console.log(req.body).

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the request you are trying to fire off to your API? What tool are you using to debug? If `req.body.location` is undefined, that would definitely be an issue :)

Comment: I am posting the following form action using the method-override package to allow me to use the PUT method.

```<form action="/location/<%= location._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">```

I am then using Model.findByIdAndUpdate within my PUT route as seen here

`router.put("/location/:id", function(req, res) {
    Location.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.location, {new: true}, function(err, updatedLocation){`

but the req.body.location is coming through blank and I can't figure out why. I'm only using node.js callbacks to track errors. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Given your console log for `req.body`, it looks like you are very close. You see that you have the data you need in there, what is missing?

Comment: Also, I would recommend learning to use a tool like Postman to test your APIs:
https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: I was actually able to find the resolution and it was the settings of bodyParser. I've included it in the question. Thanks for your help!