# Update Entire Collection In MongoDB Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a program that receive a **New** file from FTP server after some specific time , I insert the new updated file's data into my database **MongoDB** the fields remain same , only data changes in new file.. Now the problem is that **EVERY TIME I** have to insert whole new collection into database, and the collection increases accordingly.**Forexample-** first time data is of 20 records , second time 40 and then 60 and so on .The thing I want to do is I want to check which field's data is updated in **New file** before inserting new **FILE's** data , and should only update these field's data in database instead of inserting whole new document.Does MONGOOSE or MONGODB provide solution for this , means **IF I PASS A DATA AS PARAMETER , IT SOULD COMPARE MY EXISTING COLLECTION WITH MY NEW DATA** and then **Update Only UPDATED FIELDS** ..Please help me i,m stuck , thanks :) . I,m using **NODE JS** ...

```
var c = new Client();
            var connectionProperties = {
                host: 'ABC',
                user: 'ABC',
                port: 'ABC',
                password: 'ABC',
            };
            c.connect(connectionProperties);
          c.on('ready', function () {
                c.get('path-to-excel-file', function (err, stream) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    stream.once('close', function () {
                        const workBook = XLSX.readFile('Convertedfile.xlsx');
                        XLSX.writeFile(workBook, 'Convertedfile', { bookType: "csv" });
                        csv()
                            .fromFile("Convertedfile")
                            .then((jsonObj) => {
                                Model.collection.insert(jsonObj, function (err, docs) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        return console.error(err);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("All Documents insterted");
                                    }
                                });
                            })
                        c.end()
                    });
                    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ConvertedFile.xlsx'))
                })
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need *upsert* means update if document/record exists or insert/create it.

So this can be done either 1 document at a moment or in bulk, but it would need a query to find the matching document(s) first.

Since you've not provided any sample data so I can't write a sample code snippet for you but here is the link to get you started, for bulk: [Bulk.find.upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/) and for single document this thread is good : [how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)

**Update:** here is the mongodb bulk upsert in action:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;

const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', { useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(async err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('DB Connection Error ', err);
    } else {
        const db = client.db('node-cheat-db');

        // lets assume you've read all file contents and data is now ready for db operation
        let records = [
            {first: 'john', last: 'doe', email: 'johen@doe.com'},
            {first: 'jack', last: 'doe', email: 'jack@doe.com'},
            {first: 'jill', last: 'doe_updated', email: 'jill@doe.com'}
        ];

        // prepare bulk upsert so that new records are created and existing are updated
        let bulk = db.collection('users').initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            bulk.find({
        "email": records[i].email // at least 1 key should be treated as PK; in this example email is PK
        }).upsert(records[i]).replaceOne(records[i]);
        }
        bulk.execute(function (err,updateResult) {
                if (updateResult.result.ok != 1) {
                    console.log('Bulk Upsert Error');
                } else {
                    console.log(`Inserted: ${updateResult.result.nUpserted} and Updated: ${updateResult.result.nModified}`);
                }
        });
    }
});
```

sample output looks like:

> Inserted: 0 and Updated: 3

**Further Details:**

Clone node-cheat [bulk-update](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/mongodb/bulk-update.js#L8), run `node bulk-update.js` followed by `npm install mongodb`.

Comment: thanks for the link , it really helps me to start from somewhere .. I have Updated question  with my code so , can you guide me how i can acheive this in my code .. a little explaination what i am doing ! First of all , i recieve EXCEL file from FTP server , i convert it into CSV and then add CSV data into database

Comment: alright @rizwanraza, I have added code, it shows how to handle bulk upsert. Hope it helps now!