# update value in mongodb using node js express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It's update only false to true not working for true to false. I'm using node.js mongodb and express.js

This is My schema:

```
approve:{
  type: Boolean, default: false
}
```

index.js

```
.post('/update', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var value = req.value;
    console.log(req.body);
    var update_stock = stmodel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { approve: "value" } });
    update_stock.exec(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Comment: Why do you have quotes arround the value?? This `approve: "value"` will try to set `approve` to a string `value` . Just remove the quotes -> `{ $set: { approve: value } }` Also this `req.value` doesn't seem right, shouldn't it be `req.body.value`???

Comment: but { $set: { approve: "value" } working for update false to true

Comment: { $set: { approve: value } }  does't working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update/upsert a document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you are trying to set the `value` to `req.value`, it should be `req.body.value`

```
var value = req.body.value;
```

Also, you have to make sure `value` is a `Boolean`, since it needs to be a `Boolean` according to your `schema`, or you can also handle it if it is a `String` or `Boolean` like this :

```
let approve = value === "true" ? true : ( value === "false" ? false : undefined);
stmodel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { approve: approve } });
```

Comment: u have any other solution??? because it's not working

Comment: Did you try both the things? Also, can you console `value` and `typeof value`?

Comment: value:false/true  typeof value:string

Comment: Thats what i thought that the value is string, you need to edit the value to Boolean, i have updated my answer, please check