# How to get return value from Mongoose save function using axios in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, axios, mern

I am new to React JS and I created a simple application which accept UserName and Email and inserts to MongoDB.

I use `React + Node + Express + Mongoose + MongoDB` and I was able to insert the record successfully

**DB.js**

```
router.route("/insert").post(function(req, res) {

  let comments = new Comments(req.body);
  console.log(req.body)
  comments.save();
});
```

**App.js**

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/insert", {
            UserName:  username,
            UserEmail: email,
            Comments:  comments
        })
```

Now, I want to return `'numRowsAffected'` from **DB.js** to **App.js**.

Hence, I modified **DB.js** by adding callback to mongoose save() function

```
router.route("/insert").post(function(req, res) {
  let comments = new Comments(req.body);
  console.log(req.body)
  comments.save(function(err, comments, numRows) {
      if ( err ) { 
          res.send(err);
      }
      else {
          res.json({ message: 'Comments added', data: numRows });
      }
  });
});
```

However, I don't know how to change the code on **App.js** `(ie in axios.post)` to fetch the return value from **DB.js**

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mongoose.update()` with `upsert` option set to true instead of `Mongoose.save()` and read the `nModified` and `nInserted` property of `update` return value.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose) post for more detail.