# MERN POST request to update user does not update to database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, post, mern

I have a user profile which allows the user to update their information. **I am trying to make user update their email, however the updated email is not saved to database**.

**EditProfile.js**

```
//update user information on submit
const updateThisUser = (e) => {

       e.preventDefault();

       console.log(userEmail); //still shows the old input

       Axios.post("http://localhost:8800/updateUser", {
           _id: userId,
           userEmail: userEmail,

       }).then((res) => {
           if(res.data.isUpdated){
               let userId = res.data.id;
               window.alert('Your profile has been updated!');
               history.push(`/profile/${userId}`);
           }
           else{
               window.alert('!')
           }
       })};

return(
<div>
<Form onSubmit = {updateThisUser}>
               <h1 className="fs-1 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">Update My Profile</h1>
               <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="userEmail">
                   <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                   <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here" defaultValue={userEmail}
                       onChange = {(event) => {
                         setUserEmail(event.target.value);
                       }}
                     />
               </Form.Group>
</Form>
</div>
)
```

**POST request in index.js (server side)**

```
app.post("/updateUser", function(req, res) {

   const id = req.body._id;
   let isUpdated = false;

   try{
       UserModel.findOne({_id:id}, function(err, user1){
           if(user1) {
               user1.userEmail = req.body.userEmail;

               const updatedUser = user1.save();    
               res.send({
                   id: updatedUser._id,
                   isUpdated: true,
               })
           }
   
       })
       
   }
   catch(err){
       console.log(err);
   }});
```

The weird thing is the `window.alert('Your profile has been updated!');` does pop up after submitting the form, however it still does not save the new email to MongoDB.

I have also tried changing {defaultValue} to {value} for the text field input, however it won't let me type in the field.

Anyone knows the problem with my code? Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)? 
There are several approaches there.

Comment: @ViníciusCerqueiraBonifácio I have tried findOneAndUpdate and it doesn't work either. I think the problem is React is not able to detect the changed input, even with the onChange event as when I tried  ```console.log(userEmail)``` inside the updateThisUser function before the Axios.post... code, the console shows the old input instead of the newly typed one

Comment: It sounds strange. Can you try to create a sandbox reproducing that issue? Or even share the repo if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `findOneAndUpdate()` as:

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id},{email: req.body.userEmail;});
```

[How to Use findOneAndUpdate() in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#how-to-use-findoneandupdate-in-mongoose)

Comment: I think my problem is React is not able to detect the changed input, even with the onChange event