# mongoID _id not generated when upsert mongoDB operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use the `upsert` operator for inserting or updating operations with `findOneByIdAndUpdate`, In the case of inserting operation, the _id is not created. Isn't the behavior of creating a new document when it doesn't exist?

```
const newDocument = await collection.findByIdAndUpdate(
      {_id: id},
      newObj ,
      { upsert: true, new: true },
    );
```

I use `"mongoose": "^6.7.5"`

Thanks in advance :D!

I want a solution for the problem or what is the right behavior for `upsert` operator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update/upsert a document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose)

Comment: If there are no documents with `_id: id` then the `findByIdAndUpdate` with `upsert: true` will add a new document using the contents of `newObj` and give `newObj._id` a value of the `ObjectId` passed in the `id` variable (if it is a valid string that can be cast to an `ObjectId`). If this is not happening then you would have most likely been given an error but from the limited code you provided it is not clear what if any error handling you have.